# Method with multiple parameters

Tags: objective-c

I have a tile object like so

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withImageNamed:(NSString*) imageName value:(int) tileValue{
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //initilization code
    image = [[UIImageView alloc]
             initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    image.frame = self.bounds;
    image.opaque = YES;
    [self addSubview:image];

    valueOfTile = tileValue;
} return self;
}
```

I'm attempting to create an object:

```
tile1 = [[TileView alloc]
             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, 100, 150)
             value:1
             withImageNamed:@"tile1.png"];
```

I was able to get this to work when I didn't have the value information added, but it's now giving me this error: Instance method `'-initWithFrame:value:withImageNamed:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: BTW - The title of this question should be "method with multiple parameters".

Answer (score 3):

The method is defined as `initWithFrame:withImageNamed:value:`, but you're calling it as `initWithFrame:value:withImageNamed:`. You would need to call it like this:

```
tile1 = [[TileView alloc]
             initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, 100, 150)
             withImageNamed:@"tile1.png"
             value:1];
```

Comment: Bah, I feel dumb now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature and the way you invoke it don't match: the order of parameters is different. Swap the last two parameters in your call to `initWithFrame...`, and it should work.